# SQL Server stored procedure taking too long sometimes even though indexes have been added with memory grant issues

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, stored-procedures, execution-plan

I have a stored procedure that takes too long sometimes even though I have added all suggested indexes.
I keep getting the **Query had to wait for memory grant**
The query plan can be found here: [Query Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJjRlt359)

Comment: That's SQL Server 2016 SP1 which has been out of support for over 3 years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### superfund

This query is pretty well a disaster, but if the reason it's sometimes slow is that it's waiting on memory (RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE) then the server you're on is likely underpowered for the workload as a whole.

I see the `EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="417308"` and `EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2"` which would back that up.

You can artificially reduce the memory grant for the "problem" query by using the [MAX_GRANT_PERCENT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3107401-new-query-memory-grant-options-are-available-min-grant-percent-and-max-grant-percent-in-sql-server-2012-74c4c363-5f65-faa2-5cba-68cc1d689cd5) hint, and finding a value that allows it to run with less memory without spilling enough to cause a performance issue.

Since you've only posted the cached/estimated plan, I can't really tell you exactly where the issue is, but general anti-patterns here:

- [Table variables](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/software-vendor-mistakes-with-sql-server-misusing-table-variables/)
- [Scalar UDFs](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/software-vendor-mistakes-with-sql-server-scalar-user-defined-functions/) (like dbo.fn_GetUtcOffset)
- [Filtering on expressions](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/software-vendor-mistakes-with-sql-server-using-functions-in-join-or-where-clauses/) (like LocalTime)
- [Optional Parameters](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/software-vendor-mistakes-with-sql-server-handling-optional-parameters/) (col = @parameter or @parameter is null)